# How can I create an numpy array from two different numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a bumpy array from two different bumpy arrays. For example:

Say I have 2 arrays a and b.

```
a = np.array([1,3,4])

b = np.array([[1,5,51,52],[2,6,61,62],[3,7,71,72],[4,8,81,82],[5,9,91,92]])
```

I want it to loop through each indices in array a and find it in array b and then save the row of b into c. Like below:

```
c = np.array([[1,5,51,52],
              [3,7,71,72],
              [4,8,81,82]])
```

I have tried doing:

```
c=np.zeros(shape=(len(b),4))

for i in b:
    c[i]=a[b[i][:]]
```

but get this error "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

If `a` is sorted, we can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), like so -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(a,b[:,0])         
idx[idx==a.size] = 0
out = b[a[idx] == b[:,0]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [160]: a
Out[160]: array([1, 3, 4])

In [161]: b
Out[161]: 
array([[ 1,  5, 51, 52],
       [ 2,  6, 61, 62],
       [ 3,  7, 71, 72],
       [ 4,  8, 81, 82],
       [ 5,  9, 91, 92]])

In [162]: out
Out[162]: 
array([[ 1,  5, 51, 52],
       [ 3,  7, 71, 72],
       [ 4,  8, 81, 82]])
```

If `a` is not sorted, we need to use `sorter` argument with `searchsorted`.

---

**Approach #2**

We can also use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) -

```
b[np.in1d(b[:,0],a)]
```

Comment: What if array b had other indices that are not part of a.

Comment: @cryptofish Add a sample for such a case into the question?

Comment: @cryptofish What to do with those rows that don't have matches in `a`. Should they be discarded in the output `c`?

Comment: yes. I only want to include the matches of a and discard there rest in c.